# Legend not updating

Tags: javascript, sencha-charts

I seem to be having a problem with the legend udating

When the data changes in the stor the pie chart updates but the legend does not.

But to surprise its getting updated once when we reset the pie chart, as am using Reset option in interactions.

I don't know what the exact problem why legend is not updating first time itself.

when I use hard code values for the store then legend was getting updated at the first itself. For the dynamic values only the legend was not updating intially.

Please refer Some part of my code,

```
    PieChart = new Ext.chart.Chart( {

                               cls: 'pie1',

                               theme: 'Demo',

                               store: store1
                               shadow: true,

                               animate: true,

   legend: {
     position: 'top'

    //  dock: false
},
   interactions: [ {

                   type: 'reset',
                  confirm: true
                  }],


series:
    [ {

        type: 'pie',

        renderer: function(sprite, storeItem, barAttr, m, store11) {

            barAttr.fill = colors1[m % colors1.length];

            return barAttr;

        },

        field: 'data1',

        showInLegend: true,

        highlight: false,

        donut: 15,

        listeners: {

            'labelOverflow': function(label, item) {

                item.useCallout = true;

            }

        },

        callouts: {

            renderer: function(callout, storeItem) {

                callout.label.setAttributes( {

                    text: storeItem.get('Horizontal')

                }, true);

            },

            filter: function() {

                return false;

            },

            box: {

                //no config here.

            },

            lines: {

                'stroke-width': 2,

                offsetFromViz: 10

            },

            label: {

                font: 'italic 14px Arial'

            },

            styles: {

                font: '14px Arial'

            }

        },

        label: {

            field: 'Horizontal',

            display: 'rotate',

            font: '5px Arial'

        }

    }]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: There's pretty much zero info here to provide any answers! Can you provide info on the pie chart component used, the format/structure of data being returned, snippets of code that does this particular part etc. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this solved by using the following code while data getting saved into the store

```
var hrPieChart = hrPanel.items.getAt(0);
            hrPieChart.legend = new Ext.chart.Legend( {
                chart: hrPieChart,
                position: 'top',
                    dock: false
            });
            var fieldNames = [];
            hStore.each(function(rec) {
                fieldNames.push(rec.get('data1'));
            });
            hrPieChart.series.getAt(0).yField = fieldNames;
            hrPieChart.redraw(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

To update a chart's legend in Sencha Touch (Charts v1.0.0), you just need to load your store and then do an `updateStore()` in the callback.

```
var updateLegend = function(){
     store.getProxy.url = 'someData.json'; // Omit if new data is from original source.
     store.load({
        callback: function(records, options, success){
            if (success === true){
                var legend = chart.legend;
                legend.view.updateStore();
            }
        }
    });
}
```